# How to include a Bibtex reference in RMarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown, bibtex

I'm having a problem with including a Bibtex citation in my RMarkdown file. My RMarkdown file looks like this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Three Authors" 
documentclass: article
bibliography: mybib.bib
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: true
    citation_package: natbib
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: margin = 1in
---

# Introduction

This is the introduction [@sutton2008]. 
# References
```

And, my .bib file includes

```
@article{sutton2008,
    author = {A. J. Sutton and J. P Higgins},
    title = {Recent developments in meta‐analysis},
    journal = {Statistics in medicine},
    year = {2008},
    volume = {27},
    number = {5},
    pages = {625-650}
}
```

I was expecting to see a citation in my compiled file. However, when I knitted the .Rmd file, it threw an error message

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ‐ (U+2010)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Error: Failed to compile main.tex. See main.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

The main.log file includes a very long message, but towards the ends it says

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `sutton2008' on page 1 undefined on input line
 93.

(./main.bbl

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ‐ (U+2010)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

I'm using RStudio Version 1.1.383, on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This seems like another alternative solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993474/knitr-pandoc-error-package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-а-u430

Comment: Thanks. I think I've tried using xelatex, as well, at some point when I tried different solutions. But, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

After several trials, I've managed to insert a citation successfully. One thing that I've noticed I didn't mention in my question was that I started to write this manuscript in Latex and I created the .bib file there. Then, I copied that .bib file to the directory where I work on my R Markdown file. I think that led to a unicode problem (as it was mentioned in the error code). Then, I deleted everything in this .bib file, and entered the citation entry again by typing it. I saved the new form of the .bib file, and when I compiled the R Markdown file, it inserted the citation correctly into the .pdf file. So, I think there was a unicode problem. Maybe there was a more efficient solution by converting the .bib file to the correct unicode form (I think it is UTF-8 to use Bibtex in RMarkdown), but I couldn't find a way to do it.